# How to grab specific items from entire json response api calls

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, web-scraping

I want to grab only `Symbol` and `Company Name` items from the entire json data but getting
all data. How I can get above mentioned data and store in pandas `DataFrame`.

[Base_url](https://www.saudiexchange.sa/wps/portal/tadawul/market-participants/issuers/issuers-directory?locale=en)

My code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

params = {
    'sectorID': 'All',
    '_': '1630217365368'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        sym = []
        name = []
        r = req.get(url, params=params, headers =headers)
        for item in r.json()['data']:
            print(item)
        #     sym.append(item['symbol']),
        #     name.append(item['lonaName'])

        # df = pd.DataFrame(sym, name, columns=[["Symble","Company name"]])
        # print(df)
        

main('https://www.saudiexchange.sa/wps/portal/tadawul/market-participants/issuers/issuers-directory/!ut/p/z1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zi_Tx8nD0MLIy8DTyMXAwczVy9vV2cTY0MnEz1w8EKjIycLQwtTQx8DHzMDYEK3A08A31NjA0CjfWjSNLv7ulnbuAY6OgR5hYWYgzUQpl-AxPi9BvgAI4GhPVHgZXgCwFUBVi8iFcByA9gBXgcWZAbGhoaYZDpma6oCABqndOv/p0/IZ7_NHLCH082KOAG20A6BDUU6K3082=CZ6_NHLCH082K0H2D0A6EKKDC520B5=N/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to fix the way you are creating the dataframe:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

params = {
    'sectorID': 'All',
    '_': '1630217365368'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        sym = []
        name = []
        r = req.get(url, params=params, headers =headers)
        for item in r.json()['data']:
            # print(item)
            sym.append(item['symbol']),
            name.append(item['lonaName'])

        df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol':sym , 'longName':name})
        print(df)
        

main('https://www.saudiexchange.sa/wps/portal/tadawul/market-participants/issuers/issuers-directory/!ut/p/z1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zi_Tx8nD0MLIy8DTyMXAwczVy9vV2cTY0MnEz1w8EKjIycLQwtTQx8DHzMDYEK3A08A31NjA0CjfWjSNLv7ulnbuAY6OgR5hYWYgzUQpl-AxPi9BvgAI4GhPVHgZXgCwFUBVi8iFcByA9gBXgcWZAbGhoaYZDpma6oCABqndOv/p0/IZ7_NHLCH082KOAG20A6BDUU6K3082=CZ6_NHLCH082K0H2D0A6EKKDC520B5=N/')

    symbol                                           longName
0     1330                 Abdullah A. M. Al-Khodari Sons Co.
1     4001                     Abdullah Al Othaim Markets Co.
2     4191  Abdullah Saad Mohammed Abo Moati for Bookstore...
3     1820  Abdulmohsen Alhokair Group for Tourism and Dev...
4     2330                         Advanced Petrochemical Co.
..     ...                                                ...
199   3020                                  Yamama Cement Co.
200   3060                                   Yanbu Cement Co.
201   2290                   Yanbu National Petrochemical Co.
202   3007                     Zahrat Al Waha for Trading Co.
203   2240                    Zamil Industrial Investment Co.
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all data from the site, you can use their API:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.saudiexchange.sa/tadawul.eportal.theme.helper/TickerServlet"

data = requests.get(url).json()
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

df = pd.json_normalize(data["stockData"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    pk_rf_company     companyShortNameEn       companyShortNameAr                                             companyLongNameEn                                     companyLongNameAr highPrice lowPrice  noOfTrades previousClosePrice todaysOpen transactionDate      turnOver  volumeTraded  aveTradeSize  change  changePercent  lastTradePrice transactionDateStr
0            4700       Alkhabeer Income             الخبير للدخل                     Al Khabeer Diversified Income Traded Fund                   صندوق الخبير للدخل المتنوع المتداول      None     None         308               None       None            None  1.293560e+06        142791        463.61    0.01           0.11            9.07               None
1            2030                  SARCO                  المصافي                                   Saudi Arabia Refineries Co.                         شركة المصافي العربية السعودية      None     None         877               None       None            None  1.352797e+07         83391         95.09   -0.40          -0.25          162.20               None
2            2222           SAUDI ARAMCO          أرامكو السعودية                                         Saudi Arabian Oil Co.                           شركة الزيت العربية السعودية      None     None        4054               None       None            None  6.034732e+07       1731463        427.10    0.05           0.14           34.90               None


...and so on.
```

---

To get only symbol/company name:

```py
print(df[["pk_rf_company", "companyLongNameEn"]])
```

```
    pk_rf_company                                             companyLongNameEn
0            4700                     Al Khabeer Diversified Income Traded Fund
1            2030                                   Saudi Arabia Refineries Co.
2            2222                                         Saudi Arabian Oil Co.

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be way faster if you store data in pandas DataFrame and later process it.

**Example Code:**

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

params = {
    'sectorID': 'All',
    '_': '1630217365368'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        r = req.get(url, params=params, headers =headers)
        data = r.json()['data']
        df_main = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df_min = df_main.iloc[:, 0:2]
        df_min.columns = ['Symbol', 'Company name']
        print(df_min)
        

main('https://www.saudiexchange.sa/wps/portal/tadawul/market-participants/issuers/issuers-directory/!ut/p/z1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zi_Tx8nD0MLIy8DTyMXAwczVy9vV2cTY0MnEz1w8EKjIycLQwtTQx8DHzMDYEK3A08A31NjA0CjfWjSNLv7ulnbuAY6OgR5hYWYgzUQpl-AxPi9BvgAI4GhPVHgZXgCwFUBVi8iFcByA9gBXgcWZAbGhoaYZDpma6oCABqndOv/p0/IZ7_NHLCH082KOAG20A6BDUU6K3082=CZ6_NHLCH082K0H2D0A6EKKDC520B5=N/')
```

**Output:**
[image]